# stm32f030 doesn't go to sleep

Tags: sleep, stm32, cortex-m

I want to enter the sleep mode with WFI on a stm32f030 (cortex M0).

However my code doesn't seem to work on the stm32f030 but works on an stm32f103.

I think it works because when trying to flash again the f103 (with stlink utility or keil) it doesn't respond and I have to connect under reset which tends to indicate that the cpu is sleeping. But I can connect without problem the f030.

Here is my code:

`int main() {
      SetupSleep();
      __wfi();
      while(1){}
    }`

Here is the content of my SetupSleep() function:

`void SetupSleep(void){
      SCB->SCR |= (1ul << 1);
      SCB->SCR &= ~(1ul << 2);
    }`
Which according to the page 81 of the f030 programming manual (http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/DM00051352.pdf) selects Sleep mode and Sleeponexit.

Does it mean an interrupt occurs that makes the cpu exiting sleep mode ?

It is my first time using the sleep mode so maybe my implementation is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manipulating the registers directly, take a look at what the standard peripheral library does. In particular, look at `PWR_EnterSleepMode()` in `stm32f0xx_pwr.c`.

At the very least I can see that you're not executing either __WFI() or __WFE() to actually enter sleep mode. There are also the other low power modes: standby and stop that may be of interest to you.

Comment: I've looked at the PWR_EnterSleepMode() and it does what I do. I've first written __wfi in lower case because my ide didn't accept upper case but now I changed and it for upper case and it doesn't report any error, but it doesn't change anything. Actually I think it enters the sleep mode because I looked at the power consumption and it is much higher when I just write the while loop. I suspect that it has to do with the µC architecture allowing debug in sleep mode for the stm32F0 but not for the F103.